# Eclipse: Create Hello World app in C

Tags: c, eclipse, ide

This seems super basic, but I'm having trouble finding documentation online to explain it.

I have the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ 3.5.1. How can I create a simple Hello World program in C? (I have also downloaded cygwin.) Many tutorials online make reference to "Managed" and "Simple" types of projects, but I can't find that anywhere. Was that removed in 3.5.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you want to use Eclipse? For a beginner, probably the easiest way to get started with C on Windows is to use the free [Microsoft Visual C++ Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/). It's a full IDE with built in compiler and debugger, and can do everything you might need to do for learning C.

Although you have Eclipse and Cygwin right now, neither of those components actually include a *compiler* unless you specifically download that too. With that environment, you have to manually put the pieces together before you can compile and run your code.

Comment: +1 For indepth description of why it isn't so simple, and best alternitive option.

Comment: @Nate: best alternative option? for me personally, the lack of C99 support is a show-stopper...

Comment: there's no reason I have to use Eclipse. If VS has a built in compiler/debugger, I'll gladly use that.